# Getting only one result scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

all.
I am working on my first Python project and am running into a problem. I am scraping a website and only getting the last result printed out.
Nothing seems to work and I have been at it for a day now.
here is the link to the site I am trying to scrape:
https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/cat_BF_universal_audio.html

and here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/cat_BF_universal_audio.html'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "fx-product-list-entry")

for product in products:
    manufacturer = product.find('span', class_= "title__manufacturer").text.strip()
    name = product.find('span', class_= "title__name").text.strip()
    availability = product.find('div', class_ = 'product__availability product__availability--1')
    price = product.find('div', class_ = "fx-price-group product__price-group").text.strip()
    Url = product.find('a', class_ = 'product__image')['href']

print(manufacturer, name, price, availability.string.strip(), Url)
```

Comment: Move that last ```print``` statement inside the ```for-loop```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print function was outside from the `for loop` and there was NoneType problem in `availability` Tthe url that you are going to scrape is relative url and to make it working I've converted it into absolute url.Here is the full working solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/cat_BF_universal_audio.html'
page = requests.get(url)
base_url = 'https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all('div', class_="fx-product-list-entry")

for product in products:
    manufacturer = product.find('span', class_="title__manufacturer").text.strip()
    name = product.find('span', class_="title__name").text.strip()
    availability = product.find('div', class_='product__availability product__availability--1')
    stock = availability.text if availability else None
    price = product.find('div', class_="fx-price-group product__price-group").text.strip()
    Url = product.find('a', class_='product__image')['href']
    abs_url = base_url + Url

    print(manufacturer, name, price, stock, abs_url)
```

Output:

```
    Universal Audio Apollo Twin X Duo Heritage Ed. 1.090 € 
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_twin_x_duo_heritage_ed.htm?listPosition=0
Universal Audio Apollo x8p Heritage Edition 3.666 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_x8p_heritage_edition.htm?listPosition=1
Universal Audio Apollo x6 Heritage Edition 2.590 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_x6_heritage_edition.htm?listPosition=2
Universal Audio UAD-2 Satellite TB3 Octo 1.129 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_satellite_tb3_octo.htm?listPosition=3 
Universal Audio Apollo X4 Heritage Edition 2.190 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_x4_heritage_edition.htm?listPosition=4
Universal Audio Apollo Twin X Quad Heritage 1.590 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_twin_x_quad_heritage.htm?listPosition=5
Universal Audio Apollo Twin USB Duo Heritage 1.090 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_twin_usb_duo_heritage.htm?listPosition=6
Universal Audio Apollo x16 Heritage Edition 3.890 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_x16_heritage_edition.htm?listPosition=7
Universal Audio OX Amp Top Box 1.269 € None https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_ox_amp_top_box.htm?listPosition=8
Universal Audio Apollo Twin MKII Duo Heritage 990 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_twin_mkii_duo_heritage.htm?listPosition=9
Universal Audio Apollo Solo TB3 Heritage Ed. 698 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_solo_tb3_heritage_ed.htm?listPosition=10
Universal Audio Solo 610 1.090 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_solo_610.htm?listPosition=11
Universal Audio UAD-2 Satellite TB3 Octo Cust. 1.590 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_satellite_tb3_octo_cust.htm?listPosition=12
Universal Audio UAFX Starlight Echo Station 398 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_starlight_delay_pedal.htm?listPosition=13   
Universal Audio UAD-2 Satellite USB Octo 1.190 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_satellite_usb_octo.htm?listPosition=14Universal Audio UAFX Golden Reverberator 398 € 
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_golden_reverberator_pedal.htm?listPosition=15
Universal Audio UAD-2 Satellite TB3 Quad 798 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_satellite_tb3_quad.htm?listPosition=16Universal Audio UAD-2 Live Rack Core 2.990 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_live_rack_core.htm?listPosition=17    
Universal Audio UAD-2 Octo 1.190 € None https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_octo.htm?listPosition=18
Universal Audio UAFX Astra Modulation Machine 398 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_astra_modulation_pedal.htm?listPosition=19  
Universal Audio 4-710D Twin-Finity 2.590 € 
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_4710d_twinfinity.htm?listPosition=20        
Universal Audio Apollo Thunderbolt 3 Card 198 € None https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_apollo_thunderbolt_3_card.htm?listPosition=21
Universal Audio 710 Twin-Finity 888 € None https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_710_twinfinity.htm?listPosition=22
Universal Audio UAD-2 Sat Octo TB3 Ultimate 9 3.666 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_sat_octo_tb3_ultimate_9.htm?listPosition=23
Universal Audio UAD-2 Satellite USB Quad 798 €
                        In stock
                     https://www.thomann.de/intl/si/universal_audio_uad_2_satellite_usb_quad.htm?listPosition=24
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the last result because you are overriding the result every time

try this:

```
for product in products:
    manufacturer = product.find('span', class_= "title__manufacturer").text.strip()
    name = product.find('span', class_= "title__name").text.strip()
    availability = product.find('div', class_ = 'product__availability product__availability--1')
    price = product.find('div', class_ = "fx-price-group product__price-group").text.strip()
    Url = product.find('a', class_ = 'product__image')['href']
    print(manufacturer, name, price, availability.string.strip(), Url)
```